# installshield - how to let user add files to program files folder in the install

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, installshield

I am trying to create an installer that will get the project to install from my server. The project will be chosen dynamically by the user (the user has access to the server), so I can't copy the files to the installer when I create it.

I want that the files will add to to ProgramFilesFolder in the installer.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail? It's not really clear what you are doing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you want to do. Do you want to automatically add files to a project that they select and then build and MSI? [**Installshield can be run via automation**](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/AutomatingProcesses.htm) (i.e via VBScript, VB, C# etc...), and you can achieve what you want using this approach. To work with a project you start from the [**ISWiProject Object**](https://docs.flexera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm). See this answer: [Installshield Build Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281613/installshield-build-automation). And for C#: [Getting Started with InstallShield Automation and C#](https://www.revenera.com/blog/software-installation/2010/12/getting-started-with-installshield-automation-and-c/).

Personally I would use Wix instead and automate via the Heat.exe tool and standard XML editing via code.

See how Installshield compares to other setup tools: [What installation product to use? InstallShield, WiX, Wise, Advanced Installer, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544292/what-installation-product-to-use-installshield-wix-wise-advanced-installer/1546941#1546941)

Learn about **Wix**:

- [Windows Installer and the creation of WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060281/windows-installer-and-the-creation-of-wix/12101548#12101548)
- [MSI vs nuget packages: which are is better for continuous delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)
- [Newer answer on automation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62461460/129130)

Comment: This answer consists of little more than links to other answers you have provided here on Stack Overflow. Are you sure this question isn't a duplicate of one of those? If so please vote to close as such rather than posting answers like this.