# How to change product code programmatically

Tags: automation, windows-installer, installshield

I have created bat file for automatic build. It's create installer of my product. But problem is that before run automatic build script I have to change product code manually from install shield. So, is there any way to change product code automatically ? because everything is automatic except product code.

Comment: What version of Installshield are you using?

Comment: Are you using MSBuild or ISCmdBld.exe?

Comment: I am using install shield standalone build

Comment: @SteinÅsmul: insall shield 2013

Answer (score 3):

As Phil says you can do this via the **COM automation interface for Installshield**, but there are also other ways as explained here: **[Installshield Build Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281613/installshield-build-automation/19295611)**.

**Essentially**:

1. The link above shows a small sample of how to use the standalone build executable **ISCmdBld.exe** - which you might already be using.

   - Something like: `"[PATHHERE]ISCmdBld.exe" -p "MyInstaller.ism" -r SingleImage -y "1.0.0.13" -z ProductCode=%guid%`.
   - Do check the above link out - I have never used ISCmdBld.exe opting for COM automation instead.
2. The linked answer also explains how to use **msbuild**, read [Urman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281613/installshield-build-automation/19295611#19295611).
3. Finally you can use the **COM automation interface** and a VBScript (or Javascript?), and I have added a small sample below for how this can work.

I don't have Installshield 2013 available, but here is **a very rough sketch** of how you can automate the latest version 2016 via **COM automation using a VBScript**:

```vb
' On Error Resume Next

Set isproject = CreateObject("ISWiAuto23.ISWiProject")
isproject.OpenProject "C:\InstallShield 2016 Projects\TestProject.ism", False

Set isproductconfig = isproject.AddProductConfig("MyNewProduct_1.0.16")
isproductconfig.ProductName = "MyNewProduct_1.0.16"
isproductconfig.ProductVersion = "1.0.16"
isproductconfig.ProductCode = isproject.GenerateGUID
' lots of properties to set, the above should normally suffice I think...

Set isrelease = isproductconfig.AddRelease("MyNewRelease_1.0.16") 
isrelease.Compressed = True
isrelease.SetupEXE = True
' lots of properties to set...

' Save and build project
isproject.SaveProject ' For some reason the project won't save properly after it is built
isrelease.Build
isproject.SaveProject

' Report error status
WScript.Echo "Number of Build Errors: " & CStr(isrelease.BuildErrorCount)
WScript.Echo "Number of Build Warnings: " & CStr(isrelease.BuildWarningCount)

isproject.CloseProject
```

This script wasn't tested that thoroughly, and weirdly, the new product configuration and release are not saved unless you save before triggering the build. It might be something simple I have mixed up - or it might be a bug in the tool (it wouldn't be the first one).

Take it for what it is, let's hope it gets you going to work out the [**wilburys**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_Wilburys) on your own (**bugs**). I think it might run if you change `ISWiAuto23.ISWiProject` to `IswiAuto20.ISWiProject` to match the Installshield 2013 COM server version.

Crucially, you must run the VBScript from a `32-bit CScript.exe / WScript.exe` (don't ask me why). Just put a shortcut to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe` on your desktop for testing, and drag and drop your script onto it, or better yet, open a command prompt and go to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` (believe it or not this is the 32-bit folder - and [the System32 folder is 64 bit](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm) (!) - only in Windows!) and then type `cscript.exe [FullPathToVBScript]`. Obviously remember to close your ISM file in the Installshield GUI before running the script.

I like the fact that you can save the new release and product config inside the *.ism file so you have a record of compiled releases. I am not sure what ISCmdBld.exe does.

Comment: Dozens of languages support COM.  Perl, Python, NodeJS, C++/C#...  yes only 32bit is supported. :(   I would simply use IsCmdBld.exe -z Property=Value without all that complexity. (That said I'm really an MSBuild advocate so I'd using a Property Function to generate the GUID and pass that into the build using PropertyOverrides.

Comment: Probably a good idea to try **MSBuild**. I would try it, if I had a chance. As to the **COM languages**: my experience is that you get total X-files problems unless you use a language that is well tested with the COM object model in question. I have had serious strangeness with Javascript and the Windows Installer object model for example (all MSI SDK samples are in VBScript - so we know what they tested with originally). For all I know Javascript could be better for Installshield. Or C# might be well tested as well, no way to tell. I have heard people struggle a lot when trying Perl with COM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are supposed to use the InstallShield automation for this kind of thing, such as the ISWiProductConfig object that exposes the ProductCode of the MSI you're building.